# Flutter Sign in with google error: signin failed

Tags: flutter

I want to add sign in with google to my app and i started following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed

It works good because i already used it in another app. Thing is that on the new app when i add everything correctly i get an error and it doesn't authenticate. Here is the error i got in the console:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that your Firebase API keys are correct and updated with your new app?

Comment: The thing is that i already connected the firebase to the app because i use the database. So i think the connection between them works because it works to read the data

Comment: Did you add sha 1 in firebase?

Comment: no.. i will try to add one now

Comment: i added them in the firebase and i get the same error. Do i need to add the somewhere else also?

Comment: You need to download the new, updated firebase json file (containing the new sha-1) and place it in your project

Comment: same problem...

Comment: I dont understand what i did wrong.. i generated the keys, put both in firebase, downloaded the config, ran flutter clean and still doesnt work